# Keeping Flutter's just_audio and audio_service in sync for shuffle mode

Tags: just-audio

I'm working on implementing a basic version of audio service using Just Audio in Flutter. I have most of the functions figured out, but I can't figure out how to keep the MediaItem queue in sync with audio player's playlist when shuffling and unshuffling.

This is what I've tried so far:

```dart
  @override
  Future<void> setShuffleMode(AudioServiceShuffleMode shuffleMode) async {
    final oldIndices = _player.effectiveIndices!;
    switch (shuffleMode) {
      case AudioServiceShuffleMode.none:
        final list = List.generate(
            oldIndices.length, (index) => queue.value![oldIndices[index]]);
        queue.add(list);
        _player.setShuffleModeEnabled(false);
        break;
      case AudioServiceShuffleMode.group:
      case AudioServiceShuffleMode.all:
        _player.setShuffleModeEnabled(true);
        _player.shuffle();
        final playlist =
            oldIndices.map((index) => queue.value![index]).toList();
        queue.add(playlist);
        break;
    }
  }
```

This updates the queue after shuffling but doesn't allow it to go back. I'm sure there must be an easy solution but my brain can't grasp it. The [official example](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) doesn't demonstrate shuffling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest storing each audio_service `MediaItem` in the `tag` property for each just_audio `IndexedAudioSource`. Then you can easily map just_audio's effective sequence to the queue:

```dart
_player.sequenceStateStream
    .map((state) => state?.effectiveSequence)
    .distinct()
    .map((sequence) =>
        (sequence ?? []).map((source) => source.tag as MediaItem).toList())
    .pipe(queue);
```

Comment: I never even thought of that. Great idea!

Comment: I've just made a small edit to the answer since I was originally ignoring null sequences, but since the queue can also be a null list I've just let nulls pass through.

Comment: I just tried this solution, and I'm receiving this error. Unhandled Exception: type 'BehaviorSubject<List<MediaItem>?>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<List<MediaItem>>' of 'source'. The pipe method is expecting StreamConsumer<List<MediaItem>?> streamConsumer, but in this example we give it, BehaviorSubject<List<MediaItem>> queue. Did I miss something?

Comment: I have updated the answer with `(sequence ?? [])` so that a null sequence maps to an empty queue.