# audio_service and just_audio design for app that supports queuing and multiple playlists

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

I'm building a mobile app for [Koel](https://koel.dev) using Flutter and the `audio_service`+`just_audio` combo. The app basically works this way:

1. User logs in
2. App loads a big bulk of JSON data from the server
3. App parses said data into songs, artists, albums, and playlists
4. App allows user to add songs to (top/bottom/after current) / remove songs from a queue and play or shuffle them. There's only one queue in the whole app (i.e. if the user press "Play All" in a playlist screen, the queue's current content will be replaced with songs from that playlist).
5. I'm assuming here that a queue (`List<Song>`?) and a `ConcatenatingAudioSource` should always be there (albeit can be empty) so that step 4 can happen

I've been trying to implement step 4 onwards with `audio_service` and `just_audio` (`ConcatenatingAudioSource`), but not as successful so far. Essentially it's not clear to me how to design the app's architecture. Do I need to instrument a queue of `Song` and synchronize it with `audio_service` and `just_audio`, and if yes, how? When the user removes a song widget from the UI, how do I remove the corresponding `Song` from the queue and `MediaItem` from the `ConcatenatingAudioSource`? What the user taps "Play Now" on a song widget in the playlist screen, what should happen under the hood to make the player switch to that song while still keeping the queue active?

(It might be worth mentioning that the examples given by `audio_service` are pretty basic with a fixed list of songs in a fixed queue, which is hardly similar to my case. Also, certain features (e.g. queue a song to after the current one) don't seem to be available, which means I'd have to rely on `BackgroundAudioTask.onCustomAction`, which only accepts [certain data types](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/StandardMessageCodec-class.html) as arguments. `MediaItem` and my custom `Song` model objects don't seem to be supported.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your approach of keeping a single `ConcatenatingAudioSource` and just using its methods to insert, remove or replace its children. You can then listen to the `sequenceStateStream` to observe changes to just_audio's playlist and pipe them into audio_service.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648538/keeping-flutters-just-audio-and-audio-service-in-sync-for-shuffle-mode) shows how to keep the just_audio and audio_service playlists in sync using the preview of the upcoming 0.18 release of audio_service. First, store the `MediaItem` audio_service object inside the `tag` property of each item in your just_audio playlist, then map and pipe just_audio's sequence from `sequenceStateStream` onto the audio_service queue:

```dart
_player.sequenceStateStream
    .map((state) => state?.effectiveSequence)
    .distinct()
    .map((sequence) =>
        sequence?.map((source) => source.tag as MediaItem).toList())
    .pipe(queue); // <-- this is the audio_service queue stream
```

If you are instead using audio_service 0.17 or earlier the principle is still the same on the just_audio side except that on the audio_service side there is a `setQueue` method instead of a `queue` stream so you can't just pipe the stream. Instead, you would remove the `.pipe(queue)` bit at the end and do `.listen(AudioServiceBackground.setQueue)`.

The effect is that each time the effective playlist in `just_audio` changes (i.e. the playlist), it will broadcast a new queue in `audio_service`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ryan. Isn't it overkill to broadcast a whole queue (which can consist of thousands of items) for every slightest change, and won't it cause a massive rerendering and/or state update on the UI, e.g., list view position loss and so forth?

Comment: Also, I still can't wrap my head around the flow. Let's say the user taps the "Play Now" button next to a Song widget on the UI, which should effectively queue the corresponding Song right after the current one (if any) and play it. How can I achieve this with `just_audio` and `audio_service`?

Comment: 1. You probably don't want a queue with 1000 items, do you? When you broadcast a queue via audio_service, it goes through the Android media session protocol to clients such as Android Auto. I think you'd want a queue of a manageable size.

2. If you're using the sync code provided above, then all you need to do is add the song to the concatenating audio source, and it will automatically update audio_service's queue.

Comment: I certainly don’t want a 1000-song queue, but it’s up to the app user, not me :) The app can host in theory an unlimited amount of songs, for example my dogfooding version has ~5,000, and a Play All button would mean a 5,000-song queue. Some artists (Queen or Pink Floyd) has a considerable discography as well.

Comment: You probably would want to implement a limit to prevent the user doing that. As it stands, though, this is how it's designed, in order to be compatible with Android's media session protocol, but this may improve for the better with the move to media2, just not in the near term.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for your patience and for being super helpful. This is getting out of scope, but on the topic of queuing a large number of songs: I think it's a common practice TBH. For example, iOS's Music app has two buttons "Play" and "Shuffle" in the "Songs" screen, which contains _all songs_ in the user's library (which has practically no size limit). Pressing these buttons will put all songs into the queue. 
I've been trying to implement this exact feature into my Flutter app with `ConcatenatingAudioSource` and `setQueue` but the UI freezes even if the queue contains e.g. only 100 items.

Comment: Sure, but you don't need to use audio_service's `queue` stream (or `setQueue` method) unless you're interested in broadcasting the queue to external clients such as Android Auto which work this way, and have these considerations where due to the way it works you probably don't want to have such a long queue. There would be nothing to prevent you from creating your own in-app stream for broadcasting queue changes to the Flutter UI that doesn't have any performance limit, but then do something more efficient when broadcasting through to external clients.